# Shell script to execute set of commands in given directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have written following shell script to execute given set of commands in the directory of each package. It is supposed to **stop** if any command fails. It should also show the command output on the console.

It takes 3 arguments with options

1. '-b' base directory of packages
2. '-c' comma separated list of commands
3. '-p' comma separated list of packages (individual
   directories)

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Function to execute a command
executeCommand(){
  printf "\n**** Executing Command: '$1' *****\n\n"
  $1
  return $?
}


  #Initialize the variables with command line arguments
  while getopts "c:p:b:" options; do
    case $options in
        b ) set -f # disable glob
            IFS=, # split on space characters
            base_directory=$OPTARG ;; # use the split+glob operator    
        c ) set -f # disable glob
            IFS=, # split on space characters
            commands=($OPTARG) ;; # use the split+glob operator
        p ) set -f # disable glob
            IFS=, # split on space characters
            packages=($OPTARG) ;; # use the split+glob operator    
    esac
  done

  #Iterate over all packages
  for (( i = 0; i < ${#packages[@]} ; i++ )); do

    #Go to each package directory
    if executeCommand "cd ${base_directory}${packages[$i]}"; then

      #Execute all the commands one by one for current package
      for (( j = 0; j < ${#commands[@]} ; j++ )); do
        if executeCommand "${commands[$j]}"; then
          echo "Successfully Executed the Command"
        else
          break 2;
        fi  
      done
    else
      break;
    fi 
  done
```

If I execute it with following arguments it gives me an error that **No Such File or directory** however, if I manually execute `cd /local/workplace/directory1` it goes to the `directory1`

**Execution and Error**

```
~/bb-slds.sh \
    -c "build clean","build package"  \
    -p directory1,directory1 \
    -b /local/workplace/

**** Executing Command: 'cd /local/workplace/directory1' *****

/home/jramay/bb-slds.sh: line 6: cd /local/workplace/directory1: No such file or directory
```

It works fine if I don't use `getopts` and instead initialize the variables as below.

```
base_directory="/local/workplace/"

declare -a commands=(
  "build clean"
  "build package"  
  )

declare -a packages=(
  "directory1"
  "directory2"
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one. :)

You changed `IFS` during the `getopts` loop, and never changed it back to the old value. So when you write:

```
$1
```

in `executeCommand`, it doesn't treat the space as a separator between `cd` and its argument.

You need to set it back to the default value after the `getopts` is done:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

The `set -f` changes persist after `getopts` as well. You should probably just do it once before the loop, then put

```
set +f
```

after it.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Same error after chanding it to

set -f
  #Initialize the variables with command line arguments
  while getopts "c:p:b:" options; do
    case $options in
        b ) IFS=, base_directory=$OPTARG ;; # use the split+glob operator
        c ) IFS=, commands=($OPTARG) ;; # use the split+glob operator
        p ) IFS=, packages=($OPTARG) ;; # use the split+glob operator    
    esac
  done
set +f

Comment: Oops, I was wrong about it being temporary. I'll update

Comment: You were right. It worked actually I missed putting IFS=$' \t\n' 
Thanks

Comment: I only added that after you told me that it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response